# java enum type getting a bit obfuscated

Tags: java, enums

Hi I am practicing java enum these days and have been given the task of debugging some codes on these out of all i have found one very challenging here it is

```
public final class ParkingAttributes extends Enum
    {

    public static final ParkingAttributes BIKE;
    public static final ParkingAttributes CAR;
    public static final ParkingAttributes CYCLE;
    private static final ParkingAttributes ENUM$VALUES[];

    private ParkingAttributes(String s, int i)
    {
        super(s, i);
    }

    public static ParkingAttributes valueOf(String s)
    {
        return (ParkingAttributes)Enum.valueOf(com/tilzmatictech/mobile/navigation/delhimetronavigator/metro/ParkingAttributes, s);
    }

    public static ParkingAttributes[] values()
    {
        ParkingAttributes aparkingattributes[] = ENUM$VALUES;
        int i = aparkingattributes.length;
        ParkingAttributes aparkingattributes1[] = new ParkingAttributes[i];
        System.arraycopy(aparkingattributes, 0, aparkingattributes1, 0, i);
        return aparkingattributes1;
    }

    static 
    {
        CAR = new ParkingAttributes("CAR", 0);
        BIKE = new ParkingAttributes("BIKE", 1);
        CYCLE = new ParkingAttributes("CYCLE", 2);
        ParkingAttributes aparkingattributes[] = new ParkingAttributes[3];
        aparkingattributes[0] = CAR;
        aparkingattributes[1] = BIKE;
        aparkingattributes[2] = CYCLE;
        ENUM$VALUES = aparkingattributes;
    }
    }
```

One thing i know that enum is a final class and cannot be extended what i didnt find anywhere here is that enum be defined and work of ENUM$VALUES[]
 Can anyone explain me the working of this code and some good tutorials to master enum 
thanks.

Comment: This is not an enum, it's a standard class with some enum-like fields. Identifiers may contain any UTF-8 characters actually. It doesn't compile, so how should we explain how this works?

Comment: then how they have given it like extending enum?

Comment: The compiler says "Error: The type ParkingAttributes may not subclass Enum explicitly". So they didn't do it anyhow.

Comment: This simply shouldn't be an Enum. You should look up the purpose of Enums because this clearly isn't the case in which you should be creating an Enum. Also, I believe only other Enums can subclass Enum.

Comment: Looks like a reverse engineered/decompiled enum.

Comment: `Enum` is not `final`, at least not according to the 1.6 APIs, but this isn't the way you normally make one and I am not sure the compiler would actually compile that code.  Also, Java does allow $ as a valid character in the identifier.  What is confusing is what they are actually doing with `ENUM$VALUES`.  It seems to me that the person that wrote this had a weak understanding of normal Java.

Comment: @CodeChimp It does not compile.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so,how to correct reverse engineered enum?

Comment: @user1798477 At first glance I'd say it is equivalent to the enum in [the answer by Arnaud Denoyelle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20951786/466862)

Comment: @noone I didn't think it would.  But, if you read the APIs Enum is not final, so outside of the compiler thinking it was a dumb thing to do and preventing it, I'd say there is nothing else stopping someone from doing it.

Comment: @noone thanx buddy but i found it is decompiled code and hence not properly formatted and the answer is of form as described by arnaud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

If you want to declare an enum, do it like this :

```
public enum ParkingAttributes { //Implicitly a final class that extends Enum
  BIKE, CAR, CYCLE//Implicitly static (but not final!) instances of ParkingAttributes.
}
```